# How to update fields of one table using other table?

Tags: mysql

How can we update `table 1` such that it will replace `b` field value of `table 1` by that of `table 2` where `a` field value are found same?

Suppose I have two tables

**table 1**

```
fields     a    b    c
           1    5   10
           1    5    8
           2    5    0
           1    4   11
```

and

**table 2**

```
fields     a    b
           1    6
           1    7
           2    5
           1    4
```

Comment: As implied by @peter - what should happen if table1.a matches multiple rows in table2.a?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on 6th form knowledge so I'll leave the code for you to do, but here's basically how I'd do it:
Select all values from table 2
For each value, select the rows from table 1 with the matching 'a' value
Count number of matching values
If it's over one, update table 1 set 'b' as the new value where 'a' matches

Edit: Oh, just realised, the 'a' values aren't unique, unless both tables have matching ID for each row, I'm not sure you can do it.